# Missing values from dictionary loading from txt file

Tags: python, dictionary

When I print the dictionary it seems to omit over half of the words. All of the words are over 2 characters as well so should be placed into their own key in the dictionary but seemingly ignored. To test I compared a file with the exact same words as in the dictionary. 36 of the words were found whilst 45 where missing.

[Words that are not present in the dictionary.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTuz2.png)

[The dictionary with the keys being first two letters of the word.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IJTs.png)

```
d = {}
#Opens the dictionary file from variable.
with open(dictionary, 'r') as f:

    #iterates through each line
    for line in f:
        line_data = f.readline().strip()

        #Gets the first to letters of the word to act as key
        first_two = line_data[0:2]

        #Checks if line is empty
        if line_data is None:
            break

        #Checks if key is already present in dictionary, appends word to list
        if first_two in d.keys():
            d[first_two].append(line_data)

        #If key is not present create a new key and a list for the words.        
        elif first_two not in d.keys():
            list = [line_data]
            d[first_two] = list
```

Comment: Coding suggestion: avoid using `list` as a variable name.  `list` clobbers the builtin python `list` function for the duration of your function.  (I use `lst`, but to each his own)

Answer (score 1):

The program as written skips every other line: `for line in f` already reads the lines from the file, so `f.readline()` is redundant and is eating half your lines.  Try this substitution:

```
    for line in f:
        line_data = line.strip()
        ... (the rest as is)
```